# Grant permission to all columns individually in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need to create different users for my database which each have access to a subset of columns in a particular table. I realise that to do this, I need to give access to the columns separately because if I grant access to the table as a whole I cannot revoke individual column permissions. So what I'm doing now is giving permissions as follows:

```
GRANT SELECT (`col_1`, `col_2`, ... , `col_100`), SHOW VIEW ON my_db.my_table TO 'my_user'@'%';
```

This is cumbersome and messy because I have a large number of columns and is also not very practical because there are likely to be changes to the column list in the future. Is there a way to grant the permission to each column without listing the names out? Then I can revoke the individual ones per user after. Something like:

```
GRANT SELECT (SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='my_db' AND `TABLE_NAME`='my_table'), SHOW VIEW ON my_db.my_table TO 'my_user'@'%';
```

(but that gives me a syntax error so it's obviously not what I need). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can't you use a tool like HeidiSQL?

Comment: I need to provide SQL so that this is repeatable for other users so a GUI approach won't work unfortunately.

Comment: HeidiSQL prints every comand it executes in the console. You can copy and paste it in a text editor - Then find and replace the username.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, but not the way you've tried. Instead you should build a query string first. Then prepare and execute it.

```
set @user   = 'testuser';
set @host   = 'localhost';
set @schema = 'test';
set @table  = 'test_table';

set @columns = (
    select group_concat('`', column_name, '`')
    from information_schema.columns
    where table_schema = @schema
      and table_name   = @table
);

set @sql = 'GRANT SELECT({columns}) ON TABLE `{schema}`.`{table}` TO {user}@{host}';
set @sql = replace(@sql, '{columns}', @columns);
set @sql = replace(@sql, '{schema}' , @schema);
set @sql = replace(@sql, '{table}'  , @table);
set @sql = replace(@sql, '{user}'   , quote(@user));
set @sql = replace(@sql, '{host}'   , quote(@host));

prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
```

Change the four variables and the query as you need.

Answer (score 1):

How To Grant Different User Permissions:

- ALL PRIVILEGES- as we saw previously, this would allow a MySQL user
  all access to a designated database (or if no database is selected,
  across the system)
- CREATE- allows them to create new tables or
  databases
- DROP- allows them to them to delete tables or databases
- DELETE- allows them to delete rows from tables INSERT- allows them to
  insert rows into tables
- SELECT- allows them to use the Select command
  to read through databases
- UPDATE- allow them to update table rows
- GRANT OPTION- allows them to grant or remove other users' privileges

To provide a specific user with a permission, you can use this framework:

```
GRANT [type of permission] ON [database name].[table name] TO ‘[username]’@'localhost’;
```

I hope this will help you solve your issue. Never forget to flush!!!

Comment: I have already figured this part out, it's in the first code snippet in my question. My issue is finding an easier way to specify the column names than having to list them out.

Comment: @Lisa you can use * instead of using names of the databases. This will grand the user acces to all the databases.

Comment: This doesn't work for revoking columns, they have to be granted individually to be able to be revoked individually (unless there's something that I'm doing wrong).

Answer (score 0):

You can GRANT the rights to individual columns to a user, using this code:

```
GRANT SELECT (col1), INSERT (col1,col2) ON mydb.mytbl TO 'someuser'@'somehost';
```

Example taken from here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html